# SQL Query PHP website from Win7 to MAMP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, authentication, mamp

I've created a PHP login system running on a Macbook using MAMP.  When I create a new user account from a networked Win7 machine I can create the account (new account details appear in the database) To login the sql query can not find the matching username and passphrase. I have echoed what is being used to search the database and they should match/return a result.

```
rowCount(); value = 0. Should be 1.
```

Is there something specific that changes string format using a windows machine ?
Maybe there's something I should have configured within MAMP ?

Maybe you can look at my basic login system code here :  https://github.com/mo0o/login_Sysphp

Comment: Add the specific code here. The questions and answers should help people in the future. What if your repo won't exist then?
But still try to show us only the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved this issue. Stupidly I had introduced a space character at the beginning of my username field. So when the stored database username was compared with the user submitted username - they did not match.